# How to load some selected files in Media Browser

Tags: media

I have a run time list of image files with their fid's. I am using [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module to handle image files. I want to load only specific set of image files fid's in the media browser on node add/edit page.

Please help me to achieve this specific stuff.

Comment: The media browser loads its content on a View so check if you can filter that to your needs.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do like on that way. But the fid's are also need to read on run time from a multiple upload image field. and than pass it to media browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is little bit tricky. Media browser generally opens all the files. So, when we present the file field in the front end, we need to pass file type (Even we can pass fids too, after uploading the files).

On the views side either using views_query_alter or a filter in the views we need to filter them out.

Using this scenario we can alter media browser files options.